# Only array is being modified

Tags: java, variable-assignment

This is the code I have, please look at it before you read the question

```
 package ict201jansem2012;


public class Qn3b {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1;
        int b[] = {4,5};
        String s = "Good luck!";
        method1(b[1]);
        System.out.println("(1) b[0] = "+b[0]+"; b[1] = "+b[1]);
        method2(b);
        System.out.println("(2) b[0] = "+b[0]+"; b[1] = "+b[1]);
        method3(a);
        System.out.println("(3) a = " + a );
        method4(s);
        System.out.println("(4) s = " + s );
    }
    public static void method1(int b) {
        b = 7;
    }
    public static void method2(int[] b) {
        b[0] = 3;
    }
    public static void method3(int a) {
        a = 3;
    }
    public static void method4(String s) {
        s = "UniSIM";
    }
}
```

Output:
(1) b[0] = 4; b[1] = 5

(2) b[0] = 3; b[1] = 5

(3) a = 1

(4) s = Good luck!

So my question is ,
This is intresting for me to know as learning programmer. The int b array 0 index value has changed, but not the other variables like the String s and int a. Before i ran this program I roughly thought in my mind that the variable will change their values as the methods are called ,this is because the method is being called and the main method vairable such as a,s and b array are passed and then they are being modified.

So in  a nutshell why is that the b array 0 index is changed while the other variables are not changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is pass-by-value, but most values (everything that's not a primitive, in this case int[] and String) are references, which means they act like pass-by-reference.

Here's a nice writeup: http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Answer (score 3):

Because you said you were a beginner programmer, I'll do a little writeup to explain (or try to explain) **exactly** what is happening.

It is because you are passing an argument to your *method1* - *method4* methods

These arguments, themselves, are references to other objects.

When you use the assignment operator, an equals sign, you overwrite that reference for the value in the current **scope** - where variables can be 'seen'.

***In your code:***

In the case of *method1* you are creating a new reference, the variable can only be seen within that scope. That is, when you then go *b* = << expr >> you are assigning the variable b within *method1*'s scope the value, not b in the *main* scope. The same is true of your *method3* and *method4* methods, you are assigning a new value to the respective variables **within** that scope, as you are creating new references rather than altering the original objects.

But, *method2*'s code behaves differently, this is because you are mutating the object inside that code. You are altering the object directly - rather than creating a new reference inside that scope.

Consider the code below

```
int[] array = new int[] {1, 2};

public void test()
{
    method1(array);
    System.out.println(array[0] + ", " + array[1]);
    method2(array);
    System.out.println(array[0] + ", " + array[1]);
}

//  because we are working with objects, the identifier, can be different to the arrays identifier
//  in this case, I've chosen to use 'a' instead of 'array' to show this
public void method1(int[] a)
{
    //  this mutates the array object
    a[0] = 2;
}

public void method2(int[] array)
{
    //  this overwrites the method2.array but not the global array
    array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

We create a new array, with identifer 'array' in the global scope. (In Java, this would be the classes own scope)

In *method1*, we take an argument, which is the same object being passed as the global array object, so when we mutate it, both objects will change. So, the first print statement will be

"2, 2"

Where array[0] has been altered

N.B. Because we dealing with objects, the 'name' of the variable doesn't matter - it will still be a reference to the same object

However, in *method2*, we take an argument, like in *method1*, but this time we use the assignment operator to assign that variable to a new value in the scope that it's currently in - so the global *array* isn't altered, so we still print out

"2, 2"

For a beginner programmer, I would personally write a few test programs where you get to fully understand how variables and scopes work.

But just know, everytime you create a new **block** of code, a new **scope** is created, local variables to that scope can only be seen in that scope and ones below it.

For instance:

```
public void test()
{
    int a = 5;
    method1(a);
    System.out.println(a);  //  prints 5
}

public void method1(int a)
{
    // a is only viewable in the method1 scope
    //  and any scopes below it, that is, any scopes created within method1
    //  and since we use an assignment operator, we assign method1.a a value, not global 'a' a value
    a = 123;
    if (true)
    {
        // this is a new scope, variables created in this block cannot be seen outside it
        //  but can see variables from above it

        System.out.println(a);  // prints 123
    }
}
```

Here, we create a new scope inside *method1* inside the if statement, which can see a above it. However, because *method1* and *test*'s scopes are both independent, when we use the assignment operator, we assign the value of *a* to the local scope. So *a* is different in both *test* and *method1*

I hope you understand better now.
I'm not very good at conveying things, but if it even helped a little bit in understanding scopes I did well, plus, it was fun.

Answer (score 1):

`arrays` are special type of objects and memory will be allocated on HEAP. When you pass array as parameter to method it will be pass as reference-value (copy of the reference).

This means initial `b` and this new reference points to same object. Unless new reference points to another object, changes on this reference will reflect on same object. That is why you are seeing value reflected on original array.

Answer (score 0):

All of the values were passed TO the inner methods, but the inner methods returned nothing.  However, method2 modified the internal value of the array that was passed to it, so that inner value appeared modified on return.

Note that method2 is the only one where you *did not* assign to the variable (parameter) itself, but rather assigned to *an element* of the object whose reference was passed in.

There is a critical difference between modifying the reference (pointer) to an object, and modifying the object itself.